# How do I shrink a div from each side going towards its center and not going from right to left

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transform

Here is my attempt:
https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/KmqGYd

```
#box {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: black;
transition: .9s ease;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.test {
width: 0 !important;
}

#button {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

I thought transform-origin would do the trick but it doesn't apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transition `transform: scale()` instead, then `transform-origin` will work since **transform**-origin works with the `transform` property. And no need to specify it, the origin is center by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#box").toggleClass("test");
  })
  
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  transition: .9s ease;
}

.test {
  transform: scaleX(0)
}

#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
</div>

<div id="button">
  Click me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try margin: 50%;

u know what i mean ?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjOYQv)

Update:
`margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;`

top margin is 25px
right margin is 50px
bottom margin is 75px
left margin is 100px

Comment: Can you please create a working example? Your explanation is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a wrapper:

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#box").toggleClass("test");
})
```

```css
.wrapper {  width: 50px;  }

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  transition: .9s ease;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test {  width: 0 !important;  }

#button {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="button">Click me!</div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/QvgJNy)